# Java Gstreamer streaming error

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer

I am trying to play this stream
[http://217.144.16.204:1935/vod/*definst*/amlst:stv2/39512547_20180214210404/playlist.m3u8](http://217.144.16.204:1935/vod/_definst_/amlst:stv2/39512547_20180214210404/playlist.m3u8)
though gstreamer-java bindings but there's a problem that it stops after 5-6
minutes even though it is supposed to continue for a much longer time. So I tried to play it via gst-launch and again got this error after
the same time:

```
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstInputSelector:inputselector0.GstSelectorPad:sink_0:
tags = taglist, video-codec=(string)"H.264\ \(High\ Profile\)",
minimum-bitrate=(uint)20000, maximum-bitrate=(uint)47352200,
bitrate=(uint)2999078, nominal-bitrate=(uint)3592604;
ERROR: from element
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstHLSDemux:hlsdemux0:
Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
gstadaptivedemux.c(2533): _src_chain ():
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstHLSDemux:hlsdemux0:
streaming stopped, reason error (-5)
 Execution ended after 0:06:00.482537774
 Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
 Setting pipeline to READY ...
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this problem?

EDIT:
Here's how the error looks after setting GST_DEBUG=3

```
 0:06:03.753006934 10064 0000000005E7E500 ERROR           d3dvideosink d3dhelpers.c:1484:d3d_resize_swap_chain:<d3dvideosink0>  HRESULT: D3DERR_INVALIDCALL
```

Comment: I used `gst-play-1.0` with Gstreamer 1.12.4. Hit the 10 minute mark without any issues..

Comment: Well I didn't make up this error. But I have the same Gstreamer version as you do and it still crashes

Comment: Set GST_DEBUG=3 and you may get some more details on what is going on. Maybe it is related to quality switching..

Comment: It also showed this warning before the stream started: (gst-play-1.0:4372): GLib-Net-WARNING **: couldn't load TLS file database: Failed to open file 'C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\etc\ssl\certs\ca-certificates.crt': No such file or directory
Redistribute latency...

Comment: Should not be an issue I think since your playlist is not on HTTPS.

Comment: I set up the GST_DEBUG variable and it showed this error: 0:06:03.753006934 10064 0000000005E7E500 ERROR           d3dvideosink d3dhelpers.c:1484:d3d_resize_swap_chain:<d3dvideosink0>  HRESULT: D3DERR_INVALIDCALL

Comment: Its only one line.. perhaps there was more before? Anyway seems your rendering has problems. Does your screen saver trigger or something? Maybe try another renderer for testing..